# Can you play base-game Claustrophobia scenarios with De Profundis included?

Tags: claustrophobia

Perhaps stupidly, I bought both Claustrophobia and its De Profundis expansion both at once.

After doing so I discovered that the designer has stated the scenarios in the base game are not suitable for playing with the material from De Profundis.

This is a colossal pain because it means sorting and removing all the cards and tiles from De Profundis every time we want to switch back to a base game scenario.

Does anyone know why this advice was given? Does it actually break the game somehow, or it merely untested? And has anyone actually tried it to see if it works okay?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a link for where the designer stated this?

Nobody I know cares about sorting out the cards to switch back to a base-game scenario. The only concern with using De Profundis with the base game is to impose a 3-card hand limit on the Demon player's Event Cards (because the expansion cards are more powerful). You also probably don't want to use the Hellhounds.